# MediaPlayer in ListView on android

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer, listviewitem

I would like display a `ListView` with each row containing a media player to play the music in the item. So please any can help from this.

Like this:
[image: example like samosa app]

Comment: i just played a music player and then i have add in listview but i don't how to do it

Comment: nice idea! but how can we help?

Comment: any sample codes... or any suggestion to refer

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ListView` filled up with Song's/Sound's names, get that as **ID** to play a Object (***creating previously the Class***) which will have as **Attributes** *song_name* as **String** and the *song* as **MediaPlayer**, when *song_name* and the Item clicked inside the ListView does match, reproduce the song of that object.

Hope this idea helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you to use [Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html), as they do what you want and follow the best Material Design patterns.

`CardView` extends the `FrameLayout` class and lets you show information inside cards that have a consistent look across the platform. `CardView` widgets can also have shadows and rounded corners.

Create a Custom Video Player and put inside it.

[image]